# C, if statements and strcmp

Tags: c, if-statement, strcmp

I don't understand why it does not pick up on the inputs. It always displays "Invalid Input"... Help!

```
while(1)
{
    fgets(input, MAX, stdin);
    printf("%s", input);

    if(strcmp(input, "1") == 0)
    {
        add();
    }
    else if(strcmp(input, "2") == 0)
    {
        delete();
    }
    else if(strcmp(input, "3") == 0)
    {
        view();
    }
    else if(strcmp(input, "4") == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Input!\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the value stored by `fgets()` contains a trailing `'\n'`.

Try this

```
int stop = 0;
while (stop == 0)
{
    fgets(input, MAX, stdin);
    printf("%s", input);

    if (strcmp(input, "1\n") == 0)
        add();
    else if (strcmp(input, "2\n") == 0)
        delete();
    else if (strcmp(input, "3\n") == 0)
        view();
    else if (strcmp(input, "4\n") == 0)
        stop = 1;
    else
        printf("Invalid Input!\n");
}
```

did it work?

So you need to remove it from `input` or adding to the comparison string.

Comment: Thank you so very much :D Worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @iharob said, I would suggest using `strncmp` to check your inputs.  That function lets you explicitly specify how many characters to compare.  See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) for a function definition.

```
int stop = 0;
while (stop == 0)
{
    fgets(input, MAX, stdin);
    printf("%s", input);

    if (strncmp(input, "1", 1) == 0)
        add();
    else if (strncmp(input, "2", 1) == 0)
        delete();
    else if (strncmp(input, "3", 1) == 0)
        view();
    else if (strncmp(input, "4", 1) == 0)
        stop = 1;
    else
        printf("Invalid Input!\n");
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, that doesn't show the problem but it works better than mine, it would be good to check `strlen(input)` before, and then use `memcmp()` which doesn't check for the `'\0'`, although `strncmp()` will not behave very differently with `1` as the size parameter.